# How to deal with returning an object and handling errors

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, iterator, return

Thanks for checking out my question. I have the following code for a java deck. I want to step away from arrays and toy code and try using best practice and object oriented principles for this one, I'm aware that I can do this in a much simpler, but less re-usable, manner.

The end goal is to create a cardgame framework which I can use to deal with the mundane parts of deck management while concentrating on the implementation of different games.

I'm having an issue with my error handling. My idea for the draw() code is as follows -

1) If there's another card return it and move the iterator along. This will eliminate the need for a discard pile as the discards will be behind the iterator with the .last() card being the one just drawn.

2) If there isn't another card and "cards" is empty run the emptyDeck() method. This method will be implemented in subclasses. For example in solitaire you may want to end the game after running through the deck x number of times so you may not want to draw a card any more.

3) if the deck isn't empty and you have no more cards then you call the endOfDeck() method which is going to be subclassed. Again, you may want to shuffle the deck or simply reset the iterator

However I'm getting the old "must return a Card" error message. I've tried creating a custom exception but I can only specify one handler method. Can anyone suggest a smart way to do this?

```
    public abstract class Deck 
{

private ArrayList<Card> cards;
private ListIterator<Card> deckPosition = cards.listIterator();
/**
 * 
 */
public Deck() 
{   
}

public Card draw()
{
    Card drawn;

    try
    {
        if(deckPosition.hasNext())
        {
            drawn = deckPosition.next();
        }
        else if(cards.isEmpty())
        {
            emptyDeck();
        }
        else
        {
            endOfDeck();
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception when drawing a card, check try/catch block in draw() method of Deck");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally
    {
        return drawn;
    }
}

public abstract void endOfDeck();
public abstract void emptyDeck();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a method is unable to return a meaningful result due to an internal error, the method should throw an exception instead of returning just something. So when an error occurs in your draw method which the method itself can not manage, it should throw an exception itself which is then handled by the caller.

In this case I would create a new exception class `DeckEmptyException`. When the deck is empty, the draw method would throw that exception instead of returning a card. Whoever calls the draw method would then have to deal with this exception.

Comment: +1 - far better than returning a `null`, which usually just results in a `java.lang.NullPointerException` shortly after it's returned.

Comment: How would I deal with multiple catches though? As I mention I tried using custom exceptions, however I wanted to deal with a DeckEmptyException and an EndOfDeckException ( where there are still cards behind me which I can use to re-shuffle or reset the iterator)   Additionally it is not an internal error but a state that might exist that I wish to test for and handle. Maybe I should split it out into other methods but I was hoping for a smart, clean way to deal with it here

Comment: When there are multiple error condition, the `draw` method could throw a different exception for each. The `throws` keyword allows to declare an unlimited number of exceptions the method might throw. Separate methods of type boolean to check if the deck is empty or at the end could also make sense. When you have such methods, calling draw on an empty deck would be even more exception-worthy, because you expect the caller to check before drawing.

Comment: In this case how would one go about handling the different exceptions that are thrown?

Comment: A try-block can have a different catch-block for each exception type. This allows you to handle each exception differently. When you want to handle multiple exceptions in one block, you can make it catch an exception class which is a base class of them. When you want to catch any exception, you can even add a `catch (Exception e)` block. This will catch any exception not handled by a more specialized catch block. The latter is commonly referred to as Pokemon Exception Handling ("gotta catch 'em all!").